# Automatically adjust the table cells

Tags: tables

I would like to draw a table in latex, but I have a problem with the long content of a couple of cells. So, I want to make it taller instead of being wide and have all the information on one page neatly. My code is appended below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
Size & $u$ & $v$ & $W_{u,v} $ & $W_u^v$ & $W_{v,u}$ \\
\hline
$n=3$ & $0001$ & $0002$ & 
$0001, 1001, 1002, 1012, 1102, 1112, 1003, 1013$ & 
$0011, 1011, 0012, 0112, 0003, 0013, 1103, 1113$ & 
$0101, 0111, 1101, 1111, 0002, 0102, 0103, 0113$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to an MWE, Format of table depends on page layout, which is so far unknown. BTW, for the long text you can enable automatics break into several lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, a possible (nice) solution is to enable, that in the last three columns you enable to break content into several lines. This can be done by use of of columns type `p{<width>}` or `>{\centering\arraybaykslash}X` columns of package `tabularx` or `X[c]` columns of `tabularray` package. The last one enables to write simple and concise table code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[c, mode=math] cc *{3}{X[c]}},
             colsep  = 4pt, 
             row{1}  = {mode=math}
             }
\text{Size}
    & u & v & W_{u,v}   & W_u^v &   W_{v,u} \\
n=3 & 0001
        & 0002
            & 0001, 1001, 1002, 1012, 1102, 1112, 1003, 1013
                & 0011, 1011, 0012, 0112, 0003, 0013, 1103, 1113
                    &   0101, 0111, 1101, 1111, 0002, 0102, 0103, 0113
               
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]